# Choosing between JHipster and Spring boot plus angular separately

Tags: jhipster

As a junior developer I am struggling to decide which approach should I use for a prototype. Given two separate apps (Java Spring Boot and Angular) I can learn many things from scratch. On the other hand JHipster provides a skeleton and a lot of already working components to copy paste.

So what do you recommend for a junior? Should I jump to JHipster or should I built everything myself in order to conquer the basics? Would it be possible to conquer the basics from a top down approach (JHipster)??

Note: I understand that Jhipster allows the easy integration of other components f.e. provides easy docker support. But still, I am not sure whether this approach is better for someone still on the learning curve.

Comment: Hi @CapBarracudas, what did you end up doing? Mind sharing your experience?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the time you have for the prototype and if the result is really important.

Solution 1: if you have a lot of time to learn, you can start from scratch and try to build everything on your own. Then, you use JHipster and can compare what you did with JHipster, and use JHipster as a modele (as we try to keep best practices). You can take some code and integrate it to your project but not sure it will work easily. And you will see there are some parts which are really hard to code yourself as they impact all your project (ex: security)

Solution 2: use directly JHipster and focus on your use cases, using the generated codes of JHipster as example. You will learn with a good base code. And you have a good community on stackoverflow and gitter to help you.

As a JHipster team member, I would suggest the solution 2, of course :-)

Comment: I would add that in both cases you'll have to learn the technologies and junior devs tend to underestimate the effort required. It also depends on the goal of your prototype: if you build it to demonstrate a business case then maybe you could use simpler technologies than Spring Boot + Angular, if you build it also to learn these technologies then I agree with  Pascal.